# iOS moving cursor from keyboard extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-keyboard-extension

We can easily update cursor position of UITextfield like this.

```
[textField setSelectedRange:beginningRange];
```

Is it possible to update cursor position from keyboard extension? I am checking textDocumentProxy and inputView though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the length of the selection to zero.

One possible implementation:

```
+ (void)setCursorInTextField:(UITextField *)textField atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    UITextPosition *start = [textField positionFromPosition:[textField beginningOfDocument] offset:index];
    UITextPosition *end = [textField positionFromPosition:start offset:0];
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do.

```
- (void)moveCursorToLeft {
    [self.textDocumentProxy adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset:-1];
}

- (void)moveCursorToRight {
    [self.textDocumentProxy adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset:1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a uiPanGestureRecignizer to a uiview or uibutton to swipe left right.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    [_yourView
     addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

Then implement the handleGesture function to get your result.

```
-(void)handleGestureNum:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    //Making Direction Indication
float deltaPanX;
        CGPoint velocity = [gestureRecognizer velocityInView:gestureRecognizer.view];
        deltaPanX += 0.1+fabs(velocity.x/500);
        int offset = 0;
        if (deltaPanX >= 1) {
            offset = 1;
            deltaPanX = 0;
        }
        if (velocity.x > 0) {
            NSLog(@"gesture moving right: counter-:@%f",velocity.x);
            [self.textDocumentProxy adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset:offset];

        }else{
            NSLog(@"gesture moving left: counter-:@%f",velocity.x);
            [self.textDocumentProxy adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset:-offset];
        }

        if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");
        }
        else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){


            //        [animView removeFromSuperview];

        }else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed){
            // Do something if needed
        }


}
```